# Why can I not change a Sprite directly?

Tags: unity, c#

I am changing the Sprites on an array of Images.  I could think of two ways to go about it.  The first way being:

```
var images = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
foreach(var image in images)
{
    if (!image.sprite)
    {
        image.sprite = GetMySprite();
    }
}
```

This way works perfectly.  But if I try to grab the sprite itself like so:

```
var images = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
foreach(var image in images)
{
    var sprite = image.sprite;
    if (!sprite)
    {
        sprite = GetMySprite();
    }
}
```

It does not work.  The Sprite gets assigned, but it is not the original Sprite.  The Sprite attached to the Image remains null.

At first I thought, maybe Sprite is a struct? But it is not - it is a sealed class extending Object.  (And I don't think that would necessarily explain it anyways).

So why must I retain the reference to the Image when changing its Sprite attribute?

Relative Documentation:
[Unity Image](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html), [Unity Sprite](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at what's actually happening here step by step.

```
var sprite
```

You create a new variable `sprite` which doesn't point to anything yet.

```
sprite = image.sprite;
```

And in the same line you point the variable to the same object as a different variable `image.sprite` is pointing to.

```
sprite = obstacles[obstacleIndex].GetIcon();
```

Now you point `sprite` to a completely different sprite. But this doesn't do anything with the original variable `image.sprite` from which you obtained the original value of the variable `sprite`.

If you want this change to matter for the original source, you need to write the new value of `sprite` back to `image.sprite` by adding this line:

```
image.sprite = sprite;
```

Answer (score 0):

`sprite` *is* changed!

But, that's not what you want. You want to change `image.sprite`. They are both different *references* to some `Sprite`.

You're creating a second reference and then changing the second reference, rather than the reference image has. So just change `image.sprite`, not `sprite`.

Comment: Right, but why is the reference changed?  Why is it creating a new Sprite?